# How to set up prod mode to have configuration file in conf directory (not inside jar)?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I'm using activator to create my project and I use the command `universal:packageBin` to generate a `.zip` file.

I was wondering if it's possible to set up the application to read the configuration file from `conf` folder instead of the configuration from classpath ( the `.conf` file inside the jar).

Is it possible? If it's, how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration for the mechanism of telling a Play application where to pickup its config from.

To tie that in with the universal:packageBin, just pass `-Dconfig.file` to the script inside the bin directory.  e.g. if your application is called foo:

`unzip foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/foo -Dconfig-file=/path/to/app.conf`